# Install package png on Rstudio on Docker,but failed

Tags: docker, png, rstudio

I install rstudio server on Docker. When I want to install package png, I got a wrong message that

```
`* installing *source* package ‘png’ ...
** package ‘png’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    
`libpng-config --cflags` -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -
Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c read.c -o 
read.o
/bin/bash: libpng-config: command not found
read.c:3:17: fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory
#include <png.h>
             ^
compilation terminated.
/usr/local/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:132: recipe for target 'read.o' failed
make: *** [read.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘png’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/png’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘png’ had non-zero exit status`
```

I think maybe I should install a library named libpng-devel,but how to install it under docker?Would you please tell me? If it were a ubuntu or centos I know apt-get or yum,but under a docker,I am confused.

Comment: Can you provide docker file or provide some steps to recreate your image?

Comment: REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
continuumio/anaconda3   latest              2f12b7e5bd80        2 weeks ago         2.23 GB
rocker/rstudio          latest              919e13c956b8        3 weeks ago         990 MB
hello-world             latest              48b5124b2768        2 months ago        1.84 kB
d4w/nsenter             latest              9e4f13a0901e        6 months ago        83.8 kB

Comment: I only install anaconda,rstudio on docker.

Comment: Installing `libpng-dev` resolved this for me today using the rocker:rstudio image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the running container for Rstudio (e.g. `docker ps`), then use `docker exec -it <container-id>` to start a bash shell in that container. From the shell, you can install any system packages that are needed.

Source: https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/wiki/Using-the-RStudio-image#dependencies-external-to-the-r-system

Answer (score 0):

Adding to prusswan's answer above. Find out what your containers name is first on the command line with the Windows command:

```
docker -ps
```

This will give you the image id and the name if any. I'll use the id to open up a bash command line interface:

```
docker exec -ti d352815fb16b bash
```

Now we'll install the required linux library we need for png. In the bash shell type:

```
apt-get install libpng-dev
```

You should get a confirm prompt, type in y, and it will install. To exit out of the linux shell, type Cntl-D.

Now go back to your Rocker interface in your browser, and try to install png again:

```
install.packages('png')
```